# Shell escape characters for sh -c

Tags: shell, quoting, escape-characters

I need to execute a command with escaped argument(s) using sh -c.  I know the string looks pretty ugly but simple ones don't cause a problem.

The output of the echo when passed to sh -c is different then when run stand alone and I am struggling to figure out how to fix it.

Background: 
[1] I am escaping the arguments to the echo command since this is passed in and I wanted to make sure extra command were not inserted.
[2] I am using sh -c as I wanted to have the ability to use shell facilities like | or nohup etc..
[3] Probably not relevant but this is being run through an ssh connection to a remote server.

The command and output of the sh -c command is:

```
sh -c "echo \a\\\\\b\;\c"

;c
```

The command and output of the stand alone command is:

```
echo \a\\\\\b\;\c

a\\b;c
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is used to escape a few characters (like `\` itself, `"`, `$`, `` ` ``) and remove newline characters inside double quotes, so

```
sh -c "echo \a\\\\\b\;\c"
```

is like

```
sh -c 'echo \a\\\b\;\c'
```

For that sh, `\` is used to escape every character, so it becomes the same as

```
echo 'a\b;c'
```

UNIX conformant `echo`s expand `\b` into a backspace character (`^H`) which, when send to a terminal moves the cursor back one character to the left, so the `;` overwrites the `a`, which is why you see `;c`.

`echo` is a non-portable command whose behavior varies greatly from shell to shell and system to system. It is best avoided especially if given arguments that may contain backslashes or may start with a dash. Use printf instead.

```
sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "a\\\\b;c"'
```

to output `a\\b;c`.

(3 backslashes would have been enough, but it's safer to remember that within double-quotes, you need two backslashes to get one).

For `echo` implementations that expand escape sequences like yours, you'd have to double the number of backslashes.

```
sh -c 'echo "a\\\\\\\\b;c"'
```

If you want to avoid the double quotes, you'll only need to escape the `;` character which is the only one special to the shell (in addition to `\` which you've already escaped in the double-quote version).

```
sh -c 'echo a\\\\\\\\b\;c'
```

If you want to use double quotes instead of single quotes, again you'll have to double the number of backslashes.

```
sh -c "echo a\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\b\\;c"
```

And if you want to get rid of the quotes, you need to escape the space and `;` again for the outer shell.

```
sh -c echo\ a\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\b\\\;c
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (which I have accepted).  Is there a way to escape the echo so that the output would be a\\b;c  ?